# Значения на русском не отображаются корректно в режиме отладки Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, отладка, кириллица

Доброго дня :) Пишу маленькую программу по учебе. В ней я считываю текст из файла и работаю с ним. Столкнулась с проблемой - в режиме пошаговой отладки не могу посмотреть значения считываемых строк. Выглядит это следующим образом:
[image: Окно контрольных значений]
text - это вектор, элементами которого являются считанные из файла слова на русском языке. В окне контрольных значений они отображаются весьма не читаемо. Это сильно мешает исправлять ошибки (а они есть, ибо программа работает не так, как надо). Хотелось бы знать, как можно это исправить. На всякий случай уточню: без кириллицы обойтись не могу, так как на курсовую буду писать синтаксический анализатор для русского языка, так что мне это будет очень полезно.

Comment: у вас там utf-8. Поэтому так и видно. Либо используйте wstring, либо просто перейдите на cp1251/866 (по обстоятельствам).

Comment: https://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/369174/support-for-encoding-selection-in-text-visualizer.html

Comment: переход на win 1251 - помог?